# ¿La forma en que estoy creando fragments en mi app android es correcta?

Tags: android, android-fragment, desarrollo

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Java para Android que es como una encuesta con más de 100 preguntas. El usuario puede ver solo una pregunta a la vez, contestarla y pasar a la siguiente así que para cada pregunta hago un fragmento que pasa uno por uno, llamémoslo QuestionFragment. A veces, cuando el usuario va alrededor de la pregunta número 50, la aplicación falla y se restaura con problemas. Parece ser un problema de memoria pues me temo que estoy creando 100 fragments lol. La forma en que estoy creando fragmentos es este código:

```
QuestionFragment nvofrag = new QuestionFragment(nvoReac,false);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.continf_fragment, nvofrag);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Este código está dentro de QuestionFargment y se llama en el botón "siguiente pregunta", así que mi duda es ¿Estoy creando los fragmentos correctamente? o peor aún ¿Es correcta mi lógica de programación? Espero ser clara. Cualquier idea o comentario sobre cómo googlear mi problema será de grandisima ayuda.

Comment: Pues no es para nada correcta la lógica que estás siguiendo. Puedes tener las preguntas en una lista e irlas presentando una por una sin cambiar de Fragmento. Es más, puedes crear una clase donde también vayas guardando la respuesta a cada pregunta y si fuera necesario, al final del cuestionario desplegar cada pregunta/respuesta, mostrar el resultado de la evaluación, etc.

Comment: @A. Cedano
Es lo que pensé, me fuí por esa vía porque mi problema principal era que en cada pregunta cambia la vista, ya que algunas necesitan spinner, otras editext, unas otros botones y así, etc. Y no se cómo ir cambiando la vista o todo el contenido de la pantalla dinámicamente. Tienes algún consejo a groso modo de cómo hacer eso. Para más detalles: debo mostrar una pregunta a la vez y cuando el usuario la conteste, aprieta un botón y avanza a la siguiente pregunta. Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Tú puedes armar un solo layout con todo lo que necesitas digamos, un layout con spinner, con edittext, etc etc y según la pregunta que sea, muestras lo que se requiera o lo ocultas. Ten en cuenta que la construcción de las vistas tiene un coste, si lo tienes todo cargado a la primera y luego vas mostrando / ocultando es lo más óptimo. Así, desde el mismo Fragment vas mostrando cada pregunta, mostrando / ocultando los elementos de la vista que esa pregunta requiera, etc. Es más, puedes encapsular esa lógica en una clase. Es decir, puedes crear una clase `Question` y asignarles tipos ...

Comment: ... por poner un ejemplo, la `Question` de tipo `1` usa un EditText y un  Spinner, la `Question` de tipo `2` usa sólo un `EditText`, la `Question` de tipo `3` usa sólo un `TextView`, etc. Y en el programa, según el tipo de la pregunta muestras lo que tengas que mostrar. Luego, metes todas las `Question` en una lista y las manejas desde otra clase llamada `Questionnaire` que hace la evaluación, según cada respuesta dada, etc. Es decir, tira de las ventajas de la POO para esto, que existe para simplificar problemas complejos. Encapsulando toda la lógica en los objetos y relacionándolos.

Comment: @A. Cedano
Muchas gracias por tu tiempo e interés, esa lógica de las preguntas y los tipos de botones que necesito ya la tengo en una lista y todo, porque así voy pintando los fragments y lo hago por código ¿eso no es muy recomendable? Además lo que no supe es hacerlo dentro de un mismo fragment, pero voy a hacer una prueba con la idea que me das. Gracias

Comment: *"porque así voy pintando los fragments..."*, es que no se trata de *ir pintando **los** fragments*, tú cargarías **el** fragment una sola vez, ese fragment está asociado a **un** layout que contiene todos los elementos necesarios según el tipo de respuesta. Inicialmente esos elementos están todos ocultos y según el tipo de pregunta los vas mostrando / ocultando de forma dinámica, **sin cambiar de fragment**. Los elementos están siempre ahí, y se cargan una sola vez. Según el tipo de pregunta, tú determinas qué se debe mostrar, asociando los textos a lo que corresponda.

Comment: Otra opción es usar un `ViewPager` para mostrar la lista de fragments.